# How to hide anchorpoints and display anchor whenever we click on image

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Can anyone tell me how to hide anchor points in canvas using kinetic.js and display anchor whenever we click on image.
For example [check this link](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) in that we can hide anchor points.
I have done application in that i need to hide anchor points after clicking on canvas,I can take no.of images and can drag,drop,re size and save them as image.
I tried to hide anchors but unsuccessful can any one guide me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but take a look:  http://jsfiddle.net/n9FLA/1/

what you want to do is attach event handlers so that you add or remove anchor points from a group. Looking at the link you provided you should make changes like:

```
    yodaGroup.on('mouseover', function(){
         addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX(), yodaImg.getY(), 'topLeft');
         addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX()+yodaImg.getWidth(), yodaImg.getY(), 'topRight');
         addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX()+yodaImg.getWidth(), yodaImg.getY()+yodaImg.getHeight(), 'bottomRight');
         addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX(), yodaImg.getY()+yodaImg.getHeight(), 'bottomLeft');
         layer.draw();
    });
    yodaGroup.on('mouseout', function(){
        var yodaKids = yodaGroup.getChildren();
        for(var i=1; i<yodaKids.length; i++)
              yodaKids[i].hide(); // .remove() would also work, or .destroy()
        layer.draw();
    });
```

You have to structure the logic and choose the events you want, but this the way you could do it.

Comment: I will give example,the concept which I asked in this question is same like in (microsoft office word) that when we select image at that time only anchors will display.

hope anyone unterstand what i want say

Comment: thanks for the reply what have u given is working but can we use that without mouse over and mouseout

Comment: yes, just change it to whatever event you want, I used mouseover/mouseout as an example

Comment: you can do mousedown, mouseup, dragstart, etc. But what you should really do is just create a flag called 'selected' and set it to true or false when an image is clicked on and off.

Comment: As a side note, KineticJS has plans to create an Anchor plugin that will do this automatically for you. Coming sometime in May though :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply
@EliteOctagon the code which u given its working perfectly as i changed in to moseout,like anchors only can we do with the image border,what i meant to say is with anchors image border should be there whatever its happening with anchors like that only i want to do with border both should applicable on same image is this possible